# Mono permission denied to any index or root directory access in a MVC application (Orchard)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, apache, mono, centos, orchardcms

> [Wed Oct 17 23:26:57 2012] [error] [client 85.55.45.215]
>   (13)Permission denied: access to / denied
>
> [Wed Oct 17 23:26:58 2012] [error] [client 85.55.45.215]
>   (13)Permission denied: access to / denied
>
> [Wed Oct 17 23:26:58 2012] [error] [client 85.55.45.215]
>   (13)Permission denied: access to / denied
>
> [Wed Oct 17 23:29:07 2012] [error] [client 85.55.45.215]
>   (13)Permission denied: access to /Refresh.html denied
>
> [Wed Oct 17 23:33:34 2012] [error] [client 85.55.45.215]
>   (13)Permission denied: access to /Refresh.html denied
>
> [Wed Oct 17 23:33:38 2012] [error] [client 85.55.45.215]
>   (13)Permission denied: access to /index.php denied
>
> [Wed Oct 17 23:33:38 2012] [error] [client 85.55.45.215]
>   (13)Permission denied: access to /index.html denied
>
> [Wed Oct 17 23:33:38 2012] [error] [client 85.55.45.215]
>   (13)Permission denied: access to /index.html.var denied
>
> [Wed Oct 17 23:33:38 2012] [error] [client 85.55.45.215]
>   (13)Permission denied: access to /index.aspx denied
>
> [Wed Oct 17 23:33:38 2012] [error] [client 85.55.45.215]
>   (13)Permission denied: access to /Default.aspx denied
>
> [Wed Oct 17 23:33:38 2012] [error] [client 85.55.45.215]
>   (13)Permission denied: access to /default.aspx denied

I'm triying to install Orchard

This is my conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin root@localhost
    ServerName www.mydomain.com

# Change the path below to suit your configuration
DocumentRoot /var/www/www.mydomain.com/public_html

# The paths used here should be common for all Linux distributions
ErrorLog /var/www/www.mydomain.com/logs/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/www.mydomain.com/logs/access.log combined

HostnameLookups Off
UseCanonicalName Off
ServerSignature On

# Make ABSOLUTELY sure that the path in double quotes ends with a slash!
Alias / "/var/www/www.mydomain.com/public_html/"

AddMonoApplications OrchardDemo "/:/var/www/www.mydomain.com/public_html"

# Orchard is a .NET 4.0 application. If your Mono was installed in a different prefix, replace /usr/bin/ with that prefix below.
MonoServerPath www.mydomain.com /usr/local/mod-mono-server4

# Helps when you get stack traces
MonoDebug www.mydomain.com True

# Orchard assumes a case-insensitive filesystem
MonoIOMAP www.mydomain.com all

<Directory "/var/www/www.mydomain.com/public_html">
SetHandler mono
MonoSetServerAlias www.mydomain.com
</Directory>
```

These are the permissions

```
drwxrwxr-x+ 11 apache www 4096 oct 24 23:14 public_html
```

I can access LICENSE.txt or Hello.html files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved disabling SELinux as said in:
Does Mono run on Fedora Core 5

Mono will run on FC5 as long as you turn off SELinux. Otherwise, some applications may experience errors.

Some people have reported compilation problems as well, but there are no details at this point, make sure you turn off SELinux if you want to use Mono

http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_Technical