# Is there a new way of setting MONO_IOMAP with Apache2

Tags: mono, apache2, mod-mono

This is almost a wiki post, but the `MonoSetEnv MONO_IOMAP=all` options does not work for me in Apache2 w/ Ubuntu as specified in what I understand is the [official doc](http://www.mono-project.com/IOMap).

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    MonoAutoApplication disabled
    MonoSetEnv MONO_IOMAP=all
    MonoDebug true
    MonoApplications "/myapp:/pathto/myapp"
    MonoServerPath "/usr/bin/mod-mono-server4"
...
```

There seems to be a new syntax to specify it. `MonoIOMAP all` as in the following:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    MonoAutoApplication disabled
    MonoIOMAP all
    MonoDebug true
    MonoApplications "/myapp:/pathto/myapp"
    MonoServerPath "/usr/bin/mod-mono-server4"
```

Is this specific to Ubuntu or mono-server4?

Most posts still mention the `MonoSetEnv` way, I only found [this one related to an orchard CMS issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058346) that hinted me to the new syntax...

#### Versions in use

Ubuntu Server 12.04.2 LTS
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.8.1 (Debian 2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.2)
mono-server4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's documented in the `mod_mono (8)` man page as follows:

```
"MonoIOMAP"
Takes alias name and a string of the same format and meaning as the MONO_IOMAP
environment variable (see the mono(1) manpage). The effect is that mod_mono performs
the same actions as mono runtime with MONO_IOMAP in effect, as well as that the
MONO_IOMAP variable with the specified value is exported in the backend environment.
This option is necessary when you're using MONO_IOMAP in your application and there
might be static files with mixed case names - in such case mod_mono attempts to open
the file directly and sends it using apache facilities.
Default value: none
```

The `MonoSetEnv` should still work, however mod-mono itself won't act on that setting except to pass it on in the environment.